# R: Trouble fitting a 4-parameter hockeystick curve with nls

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

My dataset:

```
mydata<-structure(list(t = c(0.208333333, 0.208333333, 0.208333333, 0.208333333, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 
16, 16, 0.208333333, 0.208333333, 0.208333333, 0.208333333, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), parent = c(1.2, 1.4, 0.53, 1.2, 1, 0.72, 
0.93, 1.1, 0.88, 0.38, 0.45, 0.27, 0.057, 0.031, 0.025, 0.051, 
0.027, 0.015, 0.034, 0.019, 0.017, 0.025, 0.024, 0.023, 0.29, 
0.22, 0.34, 0.19, 0.12, 0.092, 0.41, 0.28, 0.064, 0.05, 0.058, 
0.043)), .Names = c("t", "Ct"), row.names = c(325L, 326L, 
327L, 328L, 341L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 357L, 358L, 359L, 360L, 373L, 
374L, 375L, 376L, 389L, 390L, 391L, 392L, 401L, 402L, 403L, 404L, 
805L, 806L, 807L, 808L, 821L, 822L, 823L, 824L, 837L, 838L, 839L, 
840L), class = "data.frame")
```

The function to be fitted is a hockeystick curve; i.e. it flattens off after the bending point tb:

```
hockeystick<-function (t, C0, k1, k2, tb) 
{
  Ct = ifelse(t <= tb, C0 -k1 * t, C0 -k1*tb -k2*t)
}
```

Fitting using nls:

```
start.hockey<-c(C0=3,k1=1,k2=0.1,tb=3)
nls(log(Ct)~hockeystick(t,C0,k1,k2,tb),start=start.hockey,data=mydata)
```

No matter what starting values I use, I always get this error:

```
Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
  singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

I tried both the `port` and the standard nls methods. I tried both the linearized (shown here) and the normal state of the model but neither seems to work.

Edit: As per the suggestion of Carl I tried to fit the model to a dataset where I first averaged the Ct values per value of t and still get the error.

edit: Changed the model somewhat so the `k2` value is positive instead of negative. A negative value does not make sense kinetically.

Comment: Try plotting `hockeystick(mydata$t,C0,k1,k2,tb)` vs `mydata$t` .  It's not a hockey stick.  Further, your repeated values of `t` are almost guaranteed to cause regression to fail.

Comment: So in general, I'd be better off fitting the regression to averaged values per value of t?

The hockeystick is in linearized form, so the y-axis is in logarithmic units.

Comment: tb is the 'bending point' of the hockeystick model, the point at which the curve changes its 'descent rate'.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't quite solved the `nls()` problem, but I have a few suggestions.

First of all, I would suggest revising your hockey stick function slightly to make it continuous at the breakpoint:

```
hockeystick<-function (t, C0, k1, k2, tb) 
{
   Ct <- ifelse(t <= tb, C0 -k1 * t, C0 -k1*t -k2*(t-tb))
}
```

Eyeballing:

```
par(las=1,bty="l") ## cosmetic
plot(log(Ct)~t,data=mydata)
curve(hockeystick(x,C0=0,k1=0.8,k2=-0.7, tb=3),add=TRUE)
```

[image]

I've made `k2` negative here so the decreasing slope in the second stage is *less* than in the first stage.

```
start.hockey <- c(C0=0,k1=0.8,k2=-0.7, tb=3)
nls(log(Ct)~hockeystick(t,C0,k1,k2,tb),
                        start=start.hockey,data=mydata)
```

Models with breakpoints are often non-differentiable in the parameters, but
I don't quite see how that's a problem here ...

This does work:

```
library(bbmle)
m1 <- mle2(log(Ct)~dnorm(hockeystick(t,C0,k1,k2,tb),
                  sd=exp(logsd)),
          start=c(as.list(start.hockey),list(logsd=0)),
          data=mydata)
```

The parameters are reasonable (and different from the starting values):

```
coef(summary(m1))
##         Estimate Std. Error   z value        Pr(z)
## C0    -0.4170749  0.2892128 -1.442104 1.492731e-01
## k1     0.6720120  0.2236111  3.005271 2.653439e-03
## k2    -0.5285974  0.2400605 -2.201934 2.766994e-02
## tb     2.0007688  0.1714292 11.671108 1.790751e-31
## logsd -0.2218745  0.1178580 -1.882558 5.976033e-02
```

Plot predictions:

```
pframe <- data.frame(t=seq(0,15,length=51))
pframe$pred <- predict(m1,newdata=pframe)
with(pframe,lines(t,pred,col=2))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Yes, your modification from `tb` to `t-tb` is a big improvement.

I'll check out the rest of your answer when I get home later tonight.

Comment: Could you please explain why you wrap the `dnorm` function around `hockeystick()` for the estimation? Also, for this particular compound I'll probably need to get data beween the 2-10 range for `t`...

Comment: Also, it seems the `tb` parameter is not changed at all during the fitting. Whatever value I use in hockey.start is preserved in the final parameter set. While I can usually make an educated guess from the data, I can't make that stick in a paper.

Comment: the `tb` parameter did change for the test set (see edits above).  If you're using reasonable starting values I don't know why the optimizer would get stuck.  I'm using `dnorm()` because `mle2` doesn't do least-squares, it does general maximum likelihood estimation, and `dnorm()` is a way to get it to the equivalent of least-squares fitting.

Comment: it would be more efficient and robust to fit a piecewise linear model using `lm` for a specified breakpoint and then do 1-D nonlinear optimization (`optimize`) to choose the breakpoint.  Or use the `strucchange` package.